# Volume of Truncated Octagonal Prism

Tags: geometry

I was looking for the volume of this octagonal prism shown below. It looks like this:[image]

It seems that I couldn't think of a formula that could give a volume that is specific to the problem above. I could think of formulas like $V = \frac{h}{3} \left ( A_1 + A_2 + \sqrt{A_1 A_2}\right ),$ which is, I think, I wrong, because there are different heights if I run my eyes through past the figure.

What is the volume of the octagonal prism above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume of this shape is equal to the volume of a whole prism divided by two.
[image]

Comment: Your answer (1030.33 cu. cm) is pretty close to that of my book, which is 1332 cubic centimeters, but I'm not comfortable to its difference. I think it's too much. But thanks for helping me, man!:-)

Comment: @PalautotKa, You are absolutely right, I made a mistake in finding the height $H$. I have corrected the answer. Sorry about that.